# JavaScript lastChild issue

Tags: javascript

When I add text in my text field before and after the existing paragraphs the remove button functions perfectly. However, if I click the remove button before adding elements you have to click TWICE to remove the paragraphs that were not created by a function.

What could be wrong here? I watch the DOM in Firebug as I'm adding and removing, and before the new elements are added, my remove button does not target "firstDiv" on the first click, but does so on the second click.

Here is the problem function:

```
function removeIt() {
    firstDiv.removeChild(firstDiv.lastChild);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxpeD/2/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have text nodes (spaces) at the end, so the last paragraph isn't the last child (it is the last element child).

Then, use

```
function removeIt() {
    firstDiv.removeChild(firstDiv.lastElementChild);
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/nxpeD/6/

**Compatibility**: To make it work on old browsers, you could also use

```
function removeIt() {
    if (firstDiv.lastElementChild) {
        firstDiv.removeChild(firstDiv.lastElementChild);
    } else {
        var last; 
        while((last = firstDiv.lastChild).nodeType !== 1) {
            firstDiv.removeChild(last);
        }
        firstDiv.removeChild(last);
    }
}
```

**References**

- [`lastChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.lastChild)
- [`lastElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild)

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly and solves a mystery for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
 firstDiv.removeChild(firstDiv.lastElementChild);
```

Since there are formatting new line chars in your html, that will be considered as a child as well of the div. So you need to use `lastElementChild` to get the element and ignore the formatting and and other text nodes outside.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hsceW/)**

> The last_child returned is a node. If its parent is an element, then the child is generally an Element node, a Text node, or a Comment node. Returns null if there are no child elements.

**[lastElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild)**